5e: Is this "Chronoblade" homebrew Sorcerer subclass (1st-6th lvl) balanced?
My friend made the first half of a Sorcerer subclass themed around Critical Role's dunamancy, and I think it looks cool but I'm pretty new and don't know if it's balanced.
1st Level: Blade Magic
At 1st level, you gain proficiency with light and medium armor, shields, simple weapons, and martial weapons.
After a long rest, you may bond with one weapon of your choice that you are proficient in. Bonding to a weapon in this way allows the following features:

You may use your Charisma score in place of your Strength or Dexterity when making a weapon attack
You cannot be disarmed of your bonded weapon against your will
As a bonus action, you can summon your bonded weapon from up to 60 feet away
You can use your bonded weapon as a casting focus for your Sorcerer spells
You also gain Green-Flame Blade and Booming Blade as cantrips which do not count against your total cantrips known.

1st Level: Dunamantic Spells
You learn additional spells when you reach certain levels in this class, as shown on the Dunamantic Spells table. Each of these spells counts as a sorcerer spell for you, but it doesn’t count against the number of sorcerer spells you know.

1st: Shield, Zephyr Strike
3rd: Blur, Fortune's Favor
5th: Blink, Pulse Wave
7th: Dimension Door, Banishment
9th: Temporal Shunt, Steel Wind Strike

6th Level: Ebb & Flow
At 6th level, your connection to the time stream has grown allowing you to speed up or slow down the passing of time. You gain the Haste and Slow spells and you may spend 2 sorcery points to cast either spell without expending a spell slot. These spells still require concentration, and standard spell rules still apply when cast.

Looks mostly OK, but is a tad strong
Level one. The perks are pretty similar to what the Hexblade warlock subclass does get from Hex warrior, so lets compare that:

Both get an expanded spell list, 2 spells for each of the first five spell levels. This is pretty standard, also for sorcerer subclasses. Your spell choices look a bit power-gamey, a lot of best-of effects - shield, blink, dimension door, banishment. If the flavor is martial combat, why do you have banishment? If the theme is dunamancy, why is does the first and fourth spell level have no dunamancy options at all? Why no gift of alacrity or gravity sinkhole?

The hexblade get proficiency in medium armor and shields and martial weapons, and can select one pact weapon that cannot intially be two-handed, with which they can use their prime stat, charisma. You also get light armor and simple weapons which you lack as a sorcerer, and a Weapon Bond like an Eldritch knight on top, and 2 very good melee combat cantrips that the hexblade does not get. The hexblade gets Hexblade's Curse however, which is a very good option for using your bonus action. Still, I think two free cantrips may be a bit much. I'd nix that and just allow them to pick those with their normal picks -- other than a warlock who has only 2, the sorcerer anyways gets to chose 4 cantrips, so taking one of those should not be an issue.


Level 6. You already have those spells on the sorcerer list, so if you mean to say that the sorcerer gets to know these in addition to their normally known spells, you maybe should say so explicitly.
Being able to cast those spells for 2 sorcery points is equivalent to getting 3 free sorcery points each time you cast them. (Because you could create a  3rd level slot for 5 sorcery points). At 6th level you have a total of 6 sorcery points, so if you focus on those, that would allow you to create 9 more virtual points, effectively more than doubling your points. I don't know any other sorcerer subclass that has such a way to generate cheap additional spell slots. Normally you can cast 3 third level spells on 6th, this guy can cast 6, double that -- and both are really strong spells. It seems a bit much to me. I would have it cost at least 3 sorcery points.

The Tasha's classes can cast some spells for sp equal to the level, so haste would be 3 points. They also get to change the default spells from certain lists which allow for some power gaming, I think this may benefit from doing similar in theme.

Hey, thanks for your feedback! I edited the post to remove my ask for suggestions, was not aware of that

@KeeganSanders Great I took of the comment about that.
